# SRV lookup timeout from golang on kubernetes / coreDNS

Tags: go, kubernetes, dns, coredns, kube-dns

Trying to make percona operator work:

https://github.com/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator/blob/main/cmd/peer-list/main.go#L50

The golang code do a simple SRV lookup to get all pod IPs behind a service:

```
_, srvRecords, err := net.LookupSRV("", "", svcName)
```

This give error:

```
2021/11/12 19:55:22 lookup XXX.XXX.svc.cluster.local on XXX:53: dial tcp XXXX: i/o timeout
```

But:

- the pod can access to the DNS server (curl is OK)
- I set DNS timeout to 10s via container dnsConfig
- resolution is working well `dig srv XXXXX.XXXXX.svc.cluster.local` is OK

Answer (score 0):

The issue was network!

Our infra guys have disallowed TCP traffic to the kube DNS server, they was thinking DNS need only UDP :/ which is wrong !

Kafka clustering also need DNS over TCP.